# Python speech recognition: Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

im trying to convert a Wav file to text with speech_recognition, but it always crashes. My Wav file size is around 250mb, however even with a smaller file (2mb) its still crashing.

my code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
filename = "untertanaudio.wav"
def speech(filename):
    speech_engine = sr.Recognizer()
    with open("deruntertan.txt", "w+") as af:
        with sr.AudioFile(filename) as f:
            data = speech_engine.record(f)
            text = speech_engine.recognize_google(data, language="de-DE")
            af.write(text)
            print(text)
speech(filename)
```

and my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Miche\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 894, in recognize_google
    response = urlopen(request, timeout=self.operation_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Miche\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Miche\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\Miche\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\Miche\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Miche\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Miche\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Miche\PycharmProjects\bigyikes\audio_2_text.py", line 13, in <module>
    startConvertion()
  File "C:\Users\Miche\PycharmProjects\bigyikes\audio_2_text.py", line 12, in startConvertion
    print(r.recognize_google(audio_file, language=lang))
  File "C:\Users\Miche\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 896, in recognize_google
    raise RequestError("recognition request failed: {}".format(e.reason))
speech_recognition.RequestError: recognition request failed: Bad Request

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I want to run it on my local machine due to the large file.

Comment: HTTP 400 is a bad http request. There is something in the HTTP request that is being POST'd that is failing. Can you please print the value of the variable `request`?

Answer (score 0):

The URL that is embedded within the package (http://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?) seems to be obsolete, under:

```
/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py
```

If you use other method, such as `recognize_amazon`, it should work just fine.